# Why `UIImagePickerController` always converts video file to .MOV?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I need to select .mp4 files from photo library. I am using `UIImagePickerController` to pick video file from photo library. There are so many .mp4 videos which are saved by WhatsApp or any other app. But when I select any of those video file, it converts into `.MOV` file. Is there any way to avoid it and get simple .mp4 file?

`Xcode Version: 11.6 (11E708)`
`Swift Version: 5.2`
`iOS version: 13.x`

**Code snippet**

```
let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
imagePickerController.delegate = self
imagePickerController.videoExportPreset = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
imagePickerController.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]

present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

```
extension ViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL
        print(videoURL?.lastPathComponent)
        imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Console output
`trim.798B4D00-0F09-4223-A937-44629D88C0C1.MOV`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5. I now I late but write that example how i solve this problem.

1. Init UIImagePickerController

> ```
> private func openVideoGallery() {
>     let picker = UIImagePickerController()
>     picker.delegate = self
>     picker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
>     picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
>     picker.allowsEditing = false
>     picker.videoExportPreset = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
>     present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
> }
> ```

2. Delegate method

   ```
   func imagePickerController (_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {

        guard let asset = info[.phAsset] as? PHAsset else {
            return
        }

        getOriginalFileExtension(for: asset) { (fileExtension) in
            if fileExtension != nil {
                print("Original video extension: \(String(describing: fileExtension))")
            } else {
                print("Failed to retrieve original video extension")
            }
        } }
   ```
3. Method return original asset information

> ```
> func getOriginalFileExtension(for asset: PHAsset, completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
>     let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
>     options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
>     options.version = .original
>     
>     PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: options) { (avAsset, _, _) in
>         guard let avURLAsset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset else {
>             completion(nil)
>             return
>         }
>         
>         let originalVideoURL = avURLAsset.url
>         let originalExtension = originalVideoURL.pathExtension
>         
>         completion(originalExtension)
>     }   }
> ```

Comment: As of iOS 14 you shouldn't be using `UIImagePickerController` for anything but `.camera`. To select existing media, use `PHPickerViewController`.

Comment: Yes but I don't see error use minimum deployment IOS 14, maybe if you use SwiftUI. If You want you can write your answer use PHPickerViewController. I don't found another solution to get original movie extension.